# Application of Cauchy theorem On Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm taking my first course in complex analysis and I've come across a question I haven't encountered before.

$$\int_C \frac{z dz}{(z+2)(z-1)}$$

Such that C is a circle where $|Z| = 4$.

So my approach was,
seeing that this has singularities, $z = -2, 1$. I see that they lie within the circle. Therefore, I used partial fractions to break this up into two integrals.

$$\int_C \frac{z}{3(z-1)}dz - \int_C \frac{z}{3(z+2)}dz$$

Then applying cauchy's integral formula on these seperate integrals I get. Where $f(z) = z$ in both cases.
$$= \frac{2}{3} \pi i f(1) - \frac{2}{3}\pi if(-2)$$
$$ =\frac{2}{3} \pi i + \frac{4}{3} \pi i $$
$$= 2\pi i $$

Is this the correct way to approach this integral? Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: I would have said $\frac {z}{(z-1)(z+2)} = \frac {1}{3(z-1)} + \frac {2}{3(z+2)}$ but you get to the same place.

Comment: Oh yeah, I just saw the formula had a function of z above so I thought I'd keep it. But that makes sense. Just a quick follow up, if this circle was to be clockwise what would I have to change?

Comment: If the winding are negative, then that will flip the sign.

Comment: This is what I thought, so if this was clockwise then the answer would be $-2\pi i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using partial fractions,
$$
\frac{z}{(z+2)(z-1)}=\frac{2}{3(z+2)}+\frac{1}{3(z-1)}
$$
Therefore, taking the contour integral over the curve (|z|=4),
$$
\oint_{|z|=4}\frac{z}{(z+2)(z-1)}\,dz=\oint_{|z|=4}\left(\frac{2}{3(z+2)}+\frac{1}{3(z-1)}\right)\,dz
$$
By linearity of integration, this becomes
$$
\oint_{|z|=4}\left(\frac{2}{3(z+2)}+\frac{1}{3(z-1)}\right)\,dz=\oint_{|z|=4}\left(\frac{2}{3(z+2)}\right)\,dz+\oint_{|z|=4}\left(\frac{1}{3(z-1)}\right)\,dz
$$
Cauchy's integral formula states that for a suitable function $f(z)$ and curve $\gamma$,
$$
f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,dz
$$
where $a$ is any point within the interior of the curve $\gamma$. In this case, the function $f(z)$ is constant, and the singularities are $z=-2$ and $z=1$ are within the interior of the curve, so applying the formula gives
$$
\begin{align*}
\oint_{|z|=4}\left(\frac{2}{3(z+2)}\right)\,dz+\oint_{|z|=4}\left(\frac{1}{3(z-1)}\right)\,dz&=\frac{4\pi i}{3}+\frac{2\pi i}{3}\\
&=2\pi i.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you for confirming my answer. As another follow up question, if you had say $\frac{1}{z^2 + z + 1}dz$ defined over IzI = 2, how would you approach this? I can't seem to set this one up like the previous one.

Comment: That's a bit trickier because you can't use partial fractions, so it can't be written in a form where Cauchy's integral formula applies. However, you can use the residue theorem instead because the function has two singularities within the interior of the curve.

Comment: Take a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll attempt it again, I'll let you know if I have any doubts.

Comment: So I tried attempting to find the residue of this function which gave me $\frac{i}{\sqrt(3)}$ and $-\frac{i}{\sqrt(3)}$. But won't this just give me zero, $2\pi i *$ sum of residues?

Comment: You are correct, the contour integral is equal to zero because the residue at the two singularities $z=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $z=-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ are $-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$ and $\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}$ respectively.

Comment: Great. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @AlexS Why do you think you can't use partial fraction expansion?

$$\frac{1}{z^2+z+1} = \frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{z - \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}} -\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{1}{z - \frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$

Comment: @adfriedman good point, I seemed to have overlooked that